# How to make this JS-function for popup-windows generic?

Tags: javascript, html, button, popup, popupwindow

### How to make this code generic?

The only way i managed to do this is following:

```
let popup1 = document.getElementById("popup-1");

function openPopup1() {
    popup1.classList.add("open-popup");
    overlay.classList.add("overlay");
}

function closePopup1() {
    popup1.classList.remove("open-popup");
    overlay.classList.remove("overlay");
}


let popup2 = document.getElementById("popup-2");

function openPopup2() {
    popup2.classList.add("open-popup");
    overlay.classList.add("overlay");
}

function closePopup2() {
    popup2.classList.remove("open-popup");
    overlay.classList.remove("overlay");
}
```

But thats not what i actually want cause its just repeting code. And if i would add another button3 with window3 theres the same thing again.
I need help cause i dont know how to make this generic.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can just make the functions generic by passing popup id parameter

Answer (score 0):

In the refactoring code, pass the id as an argument and check if the open-popup class exists. In the next element, you can add or remove classes.

```js
function setActivePopup(popupId) {
  const popup = document.getElementById(popupId);
  const overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");

  if (popup.classList.contains("open-popup")) {
    popup.classList.remove("open-popup");
    overlay.classList.remove("overlay");
  } else {
    popup.classList.add("open-popup");
    overlay.classList.add("overlay");
  }
}
```

test case

```js
setActivePopup("popup-1"); // Opens or closes popup-1
setActivePopup("popup-2"); // Opens or closes popup-2
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems very easy and useful but where do i put the 2 lines on the bottom for under 'test case'? I thought i can use them at the html-button onclick but then the "popup-1" in the brackets were not accepted